# How to avoid repetition in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, dry

I don't mind an occasional repetition of something when it's necessary, but in MSBuild I really don't know how to *ever* avoid repetition. It doesn't offer "functions" in the usual sense; a target can only ever get called once, even via `CallTarget`, and `<Import>` only works on `Project` level.

Here's a specific example I'm trying to de-"repetize":

```
<Target Name="Tgt1">
  <PropertyGroup><Conf1>Twiddle</Conf1><Conf2>Thing</Conf2></PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup><xxxxxxxxxxExePath>$(xxxxxxxBuildRoot)\$(Conf1)Console-xxxxxxxxed</xxxxxxxxorExePath></PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuild Projects="$(BuildSingleProj)" Targets="Build;Merge"
           Properties="Configuration=$(Conf1)$(Conf2);Platform=$(Platform);CompiledFileName=$(CompiledFileName);ProjectName=$(ProjectName);SolutionFile=$(SolutionFile);Root=$(Root);Caller=$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"/>
  <MakeDir Directories="$(xxxxxxxxorExePath)" />
  <WriteLinesToFile File="$(xxxxxxxxorExePath)\xxxxxxx.IsPortable.txt" />
  <WriteLinesToFile File="$(xxxxxxxxorExePath)\xxxxxxx.Global.Settings.xml" Lines="@(xxxxxxxLicense)" Overwrite="true" />
  <Exec Command='$(xxxxxxxxorExePath)\xxxxxxx.exe -a "$(xxxxxxxBuildRoot)\$(Conf1)$(Conf2)-Merged\xxxxxxx.exe" "$(xxxxxxxBuildRoot)\$(Conf1)$(Conf2)-xxxxxxxxed\xxxxxxx.exe"'/>
</Target>
```

I have four such targets, `Tgt1`, `Tgt2`, `Tgt3`, `Tgt4`. The **only** thing that differs between these four targets is the first line, the one that defines `Conf1` and `Conf2`.

The only more or less workable de-duplication idea that I'm aware of is by moving the shared code to a new target and calling it via the `MSBuild` task. This, unfortunately, requires a *loooooong* string of properties to be manually passed in, and this task uses rather a few (I counted 11 properties and 1 item group).

An additional requirement is that I can invoke the script with an **arbitrary** subset of these targets, e.g. `\t:Tgt2,Tgt3`.

Is there any sensible alternative to just copy/pasting this chunk of code - that doesn't involve copying around huge lists of properties instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a perfect scenario to use [Batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

You'll need to create custom [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with the appropriate metadata and then create a single Target to reference the new Items.

You can wrap each Item in it's own target like so:

```
<Target Name="Tgt1">
  <ItemGroup>
    <BuildConfig Include="Tgt1">
      <Conf1>Twiddle</Conf1>
      <Conf2>Thing</Conf2>
    </BuildConfig>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="Tgt2">
  <ItemGroup>
    <BuildConfig Include="Tgt2">
      <Conf1>Twaddle</Conf1>
      <Conf2>Thing 1</Conf2>
    </BuildConfig>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="Tgt3">
  <ItemGroup>
    <BuildConfig Include="Tgt3">
      <Conf1>Tulip</Conf1>
      <Conf2>Thing 2</Conf2>
    </BuildConfig>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

You'll then need a core target to call that will perform all of the work like so:

```
<Target Name="CoreBuild" Outputs="%(BuildConfig.Identity)">
  <Message Text="Name  : %(BuildConfig.Identity)" />
  <Message Text="Conf1 : %(BuildConfig.Conf1)" />
  <Message Text="Conf2 : %(BuildConfig.Conf2)" />
</Target>
```

Adding `Outputs="%(BuildConfig.Identity)"` to the target will make sure you batch at the target level instead of at the task level.

You can execute this from msbuild with passing arbitrary combinations of the targets as long as the last target is your core target.  For example executing this command `MSBuild.exe test.msbulid /t:Tgt1,Tgt3,CoreBuild` will give you the following output:

```
Name  : Tgt1
Conf1 : Twiddle
Conf2 : Thing

Name  : Tgt3
Conf1 : Tulip
Conf2 : Thing 2
```

Comment: But this means I can no longer build just one or just two of them, correct? Any way to preserve that ability?

Comment: You can put conditions on the Items.  I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you, though I can see the conditions becoming quite tricky if I want to include any _two_ builds. I am currently leaning towards keeping the repetition because I'd like to keep the ability to specify `/t:Tgt1,Tgt2` - the real script actually has a few more targets, and we're relying on the ability to pick arbitrary subsets like this.

Comment: I updated the answer to better fit the OP's revisions to the question.

Answer (score 6):

DRY is not a tenet of MSBuild. With that being said its not good to repeat yourself in any case, when it is **reasonably** avoidable. The answer that Aaron gave regarding batching is a good one. This is one means to prevent duplication.

One thing that I would like to point out is that at a higher level it seems like you are thinking of MSBuild as a procedural language (i.e. having functions that you can call and what not). MSBuild is much more declarative than procedural though. If you are creating MSBuild scripts and you have the mindset 'Create function X so that I can call it at point Y', then you're entering a world of pain. Instead you should think of MSBuild as phases. For example; gather files, compile, publish, etc. When you think of it in this way then it makes total sense why targets are skipped after they have been executed once (*which you've obviously observed during your trials*).

Also after having been working with MSBuild for as long as I have I've figured out that it can really be a PITA to do things in a generic/uber-reusable way. It can be done, but I would reserve that type of effort for .targets files that you know for sure will be re-used **many** times. Now a days instead of going through that I am much more pragmatic and I land somewhere in between totally hacking scripts & doing things the way I used to do. I have a set of scripts that I re-use, but besides those I try and keep things simple. One big reason for this is that there are a lot of people how know the basics of MSBuild, but very few who have a very deep knowledge of it. Creating good generic scripts requires a deep knowledge of MSBuild, so when you leave a project the person who comes in behind you will have no idea what you were doing (*perhaps good if you are a contractor? lol*).

In any case I've got a bunch of resources on batching at: http://sedotech.com/Resources#Batching.

Comment: Thanks for this insight; will hopefully save me trying too hard. I have been trying to see MSBuild as declarative, but surely even declarative languages need a mechanism for creating abstractions. Pardon me for suggesting the name "functions", that's certainly the wrong term.

Comment: I was secretly hoping there was some cool mechanism that was just unknown to me. Perhaps some way to ease the pain of passing the _same_ set of 10+ properties to several MSBuild tasks? I almost got there actually, only the properties got evaluated too soon, and I couldn't find anything like "eval" to evaluate them just as they are passed to MSBuild...

Comment: If you want to "eval" items, then you need to place the ItemGroup inside of a target which you will execute. ItemGroup elmenets outside of targets are evalueated before any target exectues, but ItemGroup elements inside of targets get evaluated at the time the target executes.